# pfSense - VPN access to the printer only

Tags: vpn, pfsense

in my small company I have a LAN network connected to the outside world via pfSense based router. On this router we have OpenVPN configured for employees. In this network we have printer and several network drives connected as well.

Now one guest is also working in our building and he is connected to outside world via some old router and generally he has different public IP, he is in different network.

But now he would like to have access to our printer. Is it possible to make that connection for him, but at the same time blocking his access to network drives? How? Another VPN with some restriction rules?